# Github actions: read branch changes on workflow_run

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have two workflows: CI (for continuous integration) and CD (for continuous delivery).
My goal is if someone makes a changes to branches other than master branches, I want to execute CD as well on that branch

But its taking ref as master in CD

ci.yaml

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - test
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, ready_for_review]
    branches:
      - master
```

cd.yaml

```
name: CD

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI"]
    types: 
      - completed

jobs:
  deployment:
    name: CD
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}
```

When I make changes to test branch, CD is not picking up the changes in test branch, instead working with defaul master config.
How to make workflow_run to pick up branch changes

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do it through a `workflow_run` event, but I believe it would be possible through a `repository_dispatch` event, as you could send the `branch reference` in the dispatch request on the CI workflow to be used on the second workflow (CD).

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood what you are looking for, i.e. having the name of the original branch whose CI workflow triggered CD, changing

```
github.ref
```

with:

```
github.event.workflow_run.head_branch
```

will solve the problem